# How to improve face recognition

Tags: c++, opencv

I am doing a project on face recognition from surveillance cameras, for that I have already used different methods like eigenface, fisherface and surf. But these methods are not giving me an accurate result when it comes to real time. Surf gives good matches for exact same images, but I need to match one image with it's own different poses(wearing glasses,side pose,if somebody is covering his face) etc. So can anyone suggest a best method to overcome these problems.

Comment: http://answers.opencv.org/question/15362/opencv-and-face-recognition/#15413

Comment: alignment + LBP histograms?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it does not show own effort.

Comment: @user3228547 you may want to try the [Signal Processing Beta](http://dsp.stackexchange.com) stack exchange. They deal with concepts involving processing audio and visual signals/ images. You may have better luck there.